# Variable assignment in a ksh script

Tags: ksh, variable

I am viewing a ksh script and I see a function where the variable has been defined as below. Can anyone explain what exactly the below assignment of variable means in ksh script?

```
temprule="\$${APPLC_NM}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @`Julie Pelletier` indicated, this is funny syntax to make a indirect variable, or a nameref. `ksh` has some specialized syntax to make this work, however. This is a feature of `ksh`, and might not work in other shells.

The more idiomatic way to write the same in `ksh` would look like this:

```
# Set up the nameref:
nameref temprule=APPLC_NM
# Assign value to AAPLC_NM
APPLC_NM=abc
# The above two statements may be executed in any order.

# Now, temprule will contain the value of APPLC_NM:
echo $temprule
abc
```

Now, no funny escaping of double `$` is necessary, and the result is arguably more readable.

Comment: Your code does not prepend the variable contents with a '$' which is the result of OP's question.  That probably means that the variable content is used as a variable name later on.

Answer (score 1):

`temprule` will be assigned '$' followed by the value of the variable `APPLC_NM`.  So if `APPLC_NM` is set to "pizza", `temprule` will become "$pizza".

Note that `temprule="\$$APPLC_NM"` would do the exact same thing.  The brackets are only needed when the variable name is followed by a character that would be valid in a variable name.